# React intl to seconds with FormattedTime

Tags: reactjs, date, ecmascript-6, react-intl

I try to convert the '00:00:00', to 0 seconds on UI with React intl.

```
<MenuItem 
  value='00:00:00'
  primaryText={
    <FormattedTime 
      second='numeric' 
      units='second'
      value={new Date(2012, 11, 20, 3, 0, 0)}
    />
  }
/>
```

How to show on UI '0 seconds'

Comment: Your question is a bit vague. Are you only interested in showing the seconds which is the last 2 characters of your string? What about `00:05:10` for example?

Comment: I just need 0 second,

Answer (score 0):

To convert "00:00:00" into just "0", you can do:

```
value={parseInt('00:00:00'.substring(6)) + " seconds"}
```

The above will take the last `00`, which are the seconds, convert it into an integer (to remove any leading zeroes) and then appends the string `" seconds"`.

Comment: Yes I can even use `${parseInt('00:00:00'.substring(6))}seconds`, I'm thought that  <FormattedTime/ > by React intl can use  Intl.DateTimeFormat  API and show the second automatically